# Airflow web-server UI authentication

Tags: authentication, security, airflow, airflow-webserver

I have setup authentication for the Airflow web-server using this file as a template:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.1/airflow/default_login.py

However, I am only redirected to login when I access the `/airflow` url or `/airflow/admin` url, not when I try to access another url within Airflow (example: `/airflow/admin/dagrun`. I want to make it so that if I access any page in Airflow before being authenticated, that I'm redirected to login.

my airflow.cfg file has this enabled under web server:

```
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.my_custom_auth
```